# How to access objects of class and instance variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I want to know how many objects I have created in a Product class and print all names stored in the class. And is there any way to store all objects in JSON format which has been defined in Product Class?

```
class Product:
   pass

a=Product()
a.name="Pune"
a.apple=2

b=Product()
b.name="Delhi"
b.apple=4
```

without assigning count in class if I want to know how much I have stored data in that class. what should I do? Is there any better way to access the "apple" 
 an instance variable of every instance object.
Is there any way to convert class object in JSON format like:

```
[{"name": "Pune", "apple":2},
 {"name": "Delhi", "apple":4}]
```

Comment: To count number of objects created, you might need something similar to `reference counting`, have a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6179182/python-how-to-count-the-number-of-objects-created

Answer (score 0):

You can use `__init__` and class variable to do that.

Whenever you create an object  of `Product` class your can add those instance variable to class list

```
class Product:
    names = []
    apples = []
    def __init__(self, name, apple):
        # self.name = name
        # self.apple = apple
        Product.names.append(name)
        Product.apples.append(apple)


a=Product("Pune", 2)

b=Product("Delhi", 4)

print(Product.names)
```

Output:

```
['Pune', 'Delhi']
```

Comment: I know this way and accept your solution but without assigning count if you want to know how much you have store data in that class and want to print all name I have assigned to every object. I am asking this because I want to count all apple which has been defined. and also want to store class objects in JSON format, so, I want know How can I access the defined object of Product class and there variable.

Comment: You should provide these details in your question and add expected output too

Comment: Ok sorry for that. Can you please help me? What should I do to access any specific instance variable of all objects?

Comment: @shivshankarkeshari check the new answer