# Python class and book counter

Tags: python, class, methods, pycharm, counting

I am writing a class named "book". Each book should have a title and an author. The class should be able to automatically count the number of books.

I am stuck here -right at the beginning- and do not know how to let this method count the books.

```
class Book:
author: str = ""
title: str = ""
 def __init__(self, author, title):
     self.author = author
     self.title = title
```

..any suggestions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: How to count the number of objects created?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6179182/python-how-to-count-the-number-of-objects-created)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically as user IlayG01 said, you can implement a counter inside the class, or use a super class that counts the created books.

```py
class Book:
   author: str = ""
   title: str = ""
   counter = 0
   def __init__(self, author, title):
      self.author = author
      self.title = title
      Book.counter += 1
```

I think this will work, but also a more 'profound' answer would be to have a super class "Books" in which you can create instances of a "Book" and count it there.

EDIT: I have checked online and found a similar solution, it was an "Employee" class.

Here is the [website's](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_classes_objects.htm#:%7E:text=To%20create%20instances%20of%20a,__init__%20method%20accepts.) answer:

```py
class Employee:
   'Common base class for all employees'
   empCount = 0

   def __init__(self, name, salary):
      self.name = name
      self.salary = salary
      Employee.empCount += 1
```

Comment: Please include a _link_ to that website.

Comment: I have done the deed.

Answer (score 0):

I made it like this, having books inside a shelf:

```
class Book:
     def __init__(self, author, title):
        self.author = author
        self.title = title
class Shelf:
    def __init__(self, books=[]):
        self.books = books
    def add_book(self,book):
        self.books.append(book)
    def count_books(self):
        return len(self.books)
Book_one = Book('Me1','Test1')
Book_two = Book('Me2','Test2')
Book_three = Book('Me3','Test3')
shelf = Shelf()
shelf.add_book(Book_one)
shelf.add_book(Book_two)
shelf.add_book(Book_three)
print(f'You have {shelf.count_books()} in your shelf')
```

Answer (score 0):

something in your logic is wrong.

each instance of book should be independent, why it should notice/changed by other book?
consider creating a parent class Books, that each instance of a book increments' a counter of books.

if, for any reason, you still want to do it in the Book class, create a class attribute, and modify it in the `__init__()` that get called for each book you create.

consider to read -

1. [Achieving loose coupling](https://livebook.manning.com/book/code-like-a-pro/chapter-10/1)
2. [Python Class Attributes](https://www.toptal.com/python/python-class-attributes-an-overly-thorough-guide)